# Combine 2 SQL queries in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Queries :

Query 1 :

```
SELECT w2.Avis,w2.Cde_Sap,w2.Don_Ordre,w2.PN_in ,w2.SN_in,w2.DATE2,w2.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
 FROM w2
 INNER JOIN client
 ON w2.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
 WHERE client.Zone='CLR' 
 SORT BY w2.Avis ;
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT w3.Avis,w3.Cde_Sap,w3.Don_Ordre,w3.PN_in , w3.SN_in,w3.DATE2,w3.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
FROM w3
INNER JOIN client
ON w3.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
WHERE client.Zone='CLR' 
SORT BY w3.Avis;
```

I want to display these 2 queries in 1 Page and SORT BY Avis . Its not working .

Comment: UNION ALL, in a derived table. ORDER BY on the result?

Comment: @jarlh Can you plz help with the code . I am new to MySQL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL`, in a derived table. `ORDER BY` on the result:

```
select * from
(
SELECT w2.Avis as Avis,w2.Cde_Sap,w2.Don_Ordre,w2.PN_in ,w2.SN_in,w2.DATE2,w2.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
 FROM w2
 INNER JOIN client
 ON w2.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
 WHERE client.Zone='CLR' 

UNION ALL

SELECT w3.Avis,w3.Cde_Sap,w3.Don_Ordre,w3.PN_in , w3.SN_in,w3.DATE2,w3.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
FROM w3
INNER JOIN client
ON w3.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
WHERE client.Zone='CLR'
) dt
order by avis
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT w2.Avis,w2.Cde_Sap,w2.Don_Ordre,w2.PN_in,w2.SN_in,w2.DATE2,w2.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
 FROM (select * from w2
       UNION ALL
       select * from w3) as w2
 INNER JOIN client
 ON w2.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
 WHERE client.Zone='CLR' 
 SORT BY w2.Avis ;
```

Comment: At least in ANSI SQL there are only one Avis column, named from 1:st SELECT. Doesn't that work with MySQL as well? Anyway, I'll add a column alias.